# Problem with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Code for restore:

```
final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
        settings.getString("user", "");
        settings.getString("pw", "");
```

Code for store:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                      editor.putString("user", etuser.getText().toString());
                      editor.putString("pw", etpw.getText().toString());
                      editor.commit();
```

This code don't work, and no error occur

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt' work? You can't get the data? how do you get it? How do you understand that you don't get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String s1 = settings.getString("user", "");
    String s2 = settings.getString("pw", "");
```

My point is - you returned the desired string, but you didn't assign its value to anything.

Comment: @user547995 upvote the answer and mark it as a solution using a check under the score.

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.putString("user", etuser.getText().toString());

editor.putString("pw", etpw.getText().toString());
```

Just as a side note, you don't need the `toString()`.